# Histogram using qplot of ggplot2 looks different from the book

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I am new to R and I am learning from the book [Hands on Programming with R](https://rstudio-education.github.io/hopr/packages.html#packages-1). I have a simple task: plot a histogram using qplot. The book and I have different graphs from the same command

```
library("ggplot2")
x <- c(1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3)
qplot(x, binwidth = 1)
```

Unlike my histogram (image below), the one in the book has this type of interval [1, 2) and thus the histogram starts from 1 and not 0.5. Appreciate your help in telling me what's wrong here.

[image: My histogram]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're doing anything wrong. I'm getting the same plot as you are getting with the code from the book.

I added `xlim` and I'm getting a slightly better plot.

```
qplot(x, binwidth = 1, xlim = c(0, 4))
```

Answer (score 0):

My best bet is either

1. The qplot function was updated at some point (unlikely that this has changed) so labels were changed.
2. The book tries to reduce confusion by only giving a segment of the code, while actually performing some relabeling behind-the-scene (and causing extra confusion). This could be done rather simply

```
qplot(c(1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3), binwidth = 1, xlab = 'x') + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1, 2, 3), labels = c('[1, 2)', '[2, 3)', '[3, Inf)'))
```